# Send mail when more than 10 matches are assigned to user in a month

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models. A User model and a Match model. A user can subscribe to my service for either 6/12/18 months on any given date.
I want to limit a user to a maximum of 10 matches per month. If the user crosses 10 matches in a month, I want to send an alert email. The 10 match quota should reset the following month. How do i achieve this?

Following are the models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    MembershipStart = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Membership Start Date")
    MembershipLength = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Length of membership in months from MembershipStart')

class Match(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: what you have tried so far to solve this?

Comment: @Sumithran I have trued adding a post_save signal on the match model and then checking the users with more than 10 matches. But no luck so far on making it work

Comment: that method should work, add that code and errors if you got some.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a signal on `Match` won't work. You should use the [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.utils import timezone

def matches_users_changed(sender, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == 'post_add':
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        added_user_ids = []
        if isinstance(instance, Match):
            added_user_ids += list(kwargs['pk_set'])
        elif isinstance(instance, User):
            added_user_ids += [instance.pk]
        today = timezone.now()
        for user_id in added_user_ids:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.match_set.filter(created_on__year=today.year, created_on__month=today.month).count() > 10:
                # Do something

m2m_changed.connect(matches_users_changed, sender=Match.user.through)
```

**Note**: `action` can have many more values e.g. `"pre_add"`, etc. which you might find more useful, refer the documentation linked above for a proper list.